# Syntax for specifying base of logarithm in Calculator

Tags: calculator

In the Programming mode of gcalctool, you have a `log` button, which calculates the logarithm, but how do I know what base it's using and how do I change it?

For example, how would I calculate the base 2 logarithm for 16?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

By default the log button calculates base-10 logarithms (while the "ln" button does, of course, base-*e* logarithms).

To specify a different base, you use a "subscript":

- Type "log" in the input field.
- Input your desired base with a subscript. This can be done either by clicking on the "downarrow-n" button (top left) and then entering the number, or by pressing Alt while typing the number.
- Finally type the number whose logarithm you want to calculate.

By the way, I found this pretty easily by accessing gcalctool's help (press F1) and looking for logarithms in the index.

Comment: To use a decimal base (e.g. 1.01), use the answer from user247983. E.g. to determine the monthly interest from an APR of 12%, I used `ln 1.12 / ln 1.01`. If I use the method from this answer (`log₁.₀₁ 1.12`), it says "Malformed expression".

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the base change formula:

```
ln(1024)/ln(2) = log (base 2) (1024)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use this frequently and like a button instead of writing out the base change formula again and again. Add within gcalculator (kde) by selecting:

> edit
>   preferences
>   functions
>         Name:       log2
>         Variable:   x
>         Expression: log(x)/log(2)
>   add
>   update
>   close
>   view
>   buttons
>   functions

now to get log2(1024):
type 1024 into the calculator and PRESS ENTER
hit the 'fun' button
select log2
the answer is 10